# Finding broken symlinks using php

Tags: php, symlink, glob

I'm writing a build/deploy script using a CLI php script.

Say I have a directory `/environment` and in it there are simply two broken symlinks.

I'm running `glob(/environment/{,.}*)`. When I foreach over the glob, all I see are `.` and `..`. The symlinks never show up in the list.

How can you loop over a directory, detect broken symlinks, and `unlink()` them using PHP?

Answer (score 8):

On a broken symlink `is_link()` returns `true` and `file_exists()` returns `false`.

Since `glob()` does not list broken symlinks, you have to list the contents in a different way.
Here is an example using `scandir()`

```
   foreach(scandir($dir) as $entry) {
        $path = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $entry;
        if (is_link($path) && !file_exists($path)) {
            @unlink($path);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `@`. Errors are desired and you have enough checks there.

Answer (score 0):

use `realpath` function:

```
foreach(scandir($dir) as $entry) {
    $path = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $entry;
    if (!realpath($path)) {
        @unlink($path);
    }
}
```